# How to get the count of an element in a tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get the count of an element in a tensor, for example, `t = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (`t` is a tensor). I can get the amount 4 of zeros by calling `t.count(0)` in Python, but in TensorFlow, I can't find any functions to do this. How can I get the count of zeros?

Comment: You can also [count each element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207218/1090562)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a built in count method in TensorFlow right now. But you could do it using the existing tools in a method like so:

```
def tf_count(t, val):
    elements_equal_to_value = tf.equal(t, val)
    as_ints = tf.cast(elements_equal_to_value, tf.int32)
    count = tf.reduce_sum(as_ints)
    return count
```

Comment: @ Daniel Slater, the return valut 'count' is a tensor, I can't compare this with a int32, for example: if I do this `if tf_count(t, val) < 6:` in the graph, it will gives error. Is there any way I can compart the return value with a int32 without runing `sess.run()'? Thanks.

Comment: No, that's how tensorflow works, things are tensors until they are put through session.run. If you want to keep running in the graph you can going with tf.less(tf_count(t, val), 6) but again the result there is a tensor.

Comment: Salter, Got that, I have decided to give up using it. Thank you very much for your kind help :)

Comment: In Daniel's code above I believe `tf.equals` should be `tf.equal`.

Comment: Would it not have smaller memory footprint if you cast to tf.int8?

Comment: @fabian789 It would, but the downside is the size would limited. That parameter should be adjusted as needed for the specific case.

Comment: @DanielSlater Aaah it affects the reduce_sum as well? Ha, I was so confused because I was running into a bug when using tf.int8!

Answer (score 7):

To count just a specific element you can create a boolean mask, convert it to `int` and sum it up:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.constant([6, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 6, 7])
res = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(X, 3), tf.int32))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(res)
```

Also you can count every element in the list/tensor using [tf.unique_with_counts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts);

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.constant([6, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 6, 7])
y, idx, cnts = tf.unique_with_counts(X)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, _, b = sess.run([y, idx, cnts])
    print a
    print b
```

Answer (score 2):

An addition to Slater's answer above. If you want to get the count of *all* the elements, you can use `one_hot` and `reduce_sum` to avoid any looping within python. For example, the code-snippet below returns a vocab, ordered by occurrences within a word_tensor.

```
def build_vocab(word_tensor, vocab_size): 
  unique, idx = tf.unique(word_tensor)
  counts_one_hot = tf.one_hot(
      idx, 
      tf.shape(unique)[0],
      dtype=tf.int32
  )
  counts = tf.reduce_sum(counts_one_hot, 0)
  _, indices = tf.nn.top_k(counts, k=vocab_size)
  return tf.gather(unique, indices)
```

EDIT: After a little experimentation, I discovered it's pretty easy for the `one_hot` tensor to blow up beyond TF's maximum tensor size. It's likely more efficient (if a little less elegant) to replace the `counts` call with something like this:

```
counts = tf.foldl(
  lambda counts, item: counts + tf.one_hot(
      item, tf.shape(unique)[0], dtype=tf.int32),
  idx,
  initializer=tf.zeros_like(unique, dtype=tf.int32),
  back_prop=False
)
```